# How do I setup a login for my Ubuntu?

Tags: login, login-screen

I'm obviously a total newb, still trying to figure out some of my basic setup here. I searched, but didn't see any question quite like this, so..

I want to set up my Ubuntu so that when I boot it, it asks me for a password, and maybe also has a "guest" login with non-admin rights.

My current set up: I have 18.04 on a USB thumb-drive (planning to install it to my hard drive this weekend, if all goes well), running on a mid-2009 Macbook (yeah, I know, that's old). I want to run it as dual-boot so I have a partition with Ubuntu and another with OS El Capitan, I'm struggling a bit with installing rEFInd, but I think I'll also have that figured out soon, too.

Right now, when I boot up to Ubuntu, I just get the black screen and select Try Ubuntu without installing, and it just opens right up. It just seems heinously insecure to me. Yesterday I used the terminal to give myself a name and admin rights, but from booting, if i input 'whomami' in the terminal, it outputs 'ubuntu'. Don't know if that's normal or not.

Any help is appreciated, even corrections if I'm not looking at things the right way or something. I'll give further info if needed.

Comment: Setting your login is, um, part of normal install. Your LiveUSB is not an install - it's the try-me environment. You have not installed Ubuntu yet.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was assuming that even in the 'tryout' mode, it would have you setup a login, or that you'd have the option, but I suppose that's not the case. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother trying to get rEFInd installed at all, you would probably break the EFI on the MacBook and brick it.

First you need to shrink your current macOS partition to give yourself space to install Ubuntu. You should be able to use Disk Manager in macOS to do that.

To dual boot the MacBook, hold the Option key down whilst you turn it on. You should then be able to boot from the USB drive and install Ubuntu onto the HDD/SSD.

At that stage is when you define your Username, Password etc.

Comment: Thanks, I already have the partition done, and I've been booting, so-to-speak, from the USB w/ the Option key like you describe. This may be off-topic and i may have to create a new thread, but do you use dual-boot post-hard-drive Ubuntu install, and if so, can you do it just by holding down the Opt key? The reason I ask, is because every tutorial and/or YT vid I've seen talks about rEFInd, it seems that it, or at least another 3rd pty. boot-manager is either necessary or at least saves a heck of a lot of trouble. It seems rEFInd can be tricky to install, but lots of people use it & get by.